# Binance API Error Code: "code": -1022, "msg": "Signature for this request is not valid."

Tags: api, binance

I have a problem with the Binance API. I use HTTP request from Integromat, but I always get the following error message:

"code": -1022,
"msg": "Signature for this request is not valid."

URL I use: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account

I created the signature with HMAC SHA256 and verified it via this website: https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output

I used this example (https://dev.binance.vision/t/faq-signature-for-this-request-is-not-valid/176) and compared the output code, it matches exactly, so mine should be correct too.

I requested the timestamp from Binance via HTTP request and added +1000 milli seconds.

I don't understand why I still get this error message although the SHA256 hash is correct.

Does anyone have any idea? Attached are a image from integromat.[image: Integromat Picture]

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you forgot to include the `&recvWindow=5000` in the SHA256 operation so the signature isn't correct.

[image: correct signature parameter]

Answer (score 0):

I finally made this work :)   in integromat you calc the sha correct but the req should be made in url otherwise the output is not sha hmac
url url//../v3/account?timestamp={{2.timestamp}}